# Compilation of C++14 in qtcreator

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator, c++14

I have a qt project containing parts in `C++14`.

Recently, I changed my ubuntu distro. Now I have 16.04 LTS and I installed Qt creator 4.02 (built on jun 13).

In order to enable `C++14` compilation, I put in the project file:

```
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -std=c++14
```

However, when building project, the IDE generates the following command:

```
g++ -c -pipe -std=c++14 -g -O0 -g -std=gnu++11 -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT ...
```

As seen, the generated `makefile` puts the flag `-std=gnu++11` which overrides the flag for `C++14`. This did not happen with my previous distro (LTS 12.04, same qt creator version).

I tried with

```
CONFIG += -std=c++14
```

But the behavior is the same.

Could someone give any clue?

Comment: If I ran into this I would recursive grep for `"gnu++11"` in my config files for this project, and the config files for your qt creator, and failing that in my bin diroctories.  Failing that, hard-drive wide.  It is probably some innocuous setting somewhere...

Comment: Try `CONFIG += C++14`

Comment: @JonHarper You should have posted it as the correct answer!

Comment: Add `QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_CXX11 = -std=c++14` to your _*.pro_ file. It seems, that your _*.pro_ file already contains `CONFIG += c++11` directive.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of:

```
CONFIG += -std=c++14
```

Use:

```
CONFIG += c++14
```

Comment: But see also [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42724650/1329652) for recent MinGW on Windows that's not directly targeted by Qt as of 5.8.0 at least.

Answer (score 2):

You can fix it radically. By changing config files.

First of all you need the library path, used in your project. The path you can determine looking at *Projects* panel (`Ctrl + 5`) and remembering the name of a "Kit" over the `(Build|Run)` buttons, then follow the `Tools -> Options -> Build & Run -> Kits`, select the "Kit" you remember previously, then you can see `Qt version:` line contents, after that on `Qt versions` tab you can see the corresponding full library path you need. In my case I see `/usr/local/Qt-5.4.1/`.

In `/usr/local/Qt-5.4.1/mkspecs/common/g++-base.conf` file (you may have another path for *Qt* library installed), you can change `QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_CXX11` or `QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_CXX14` (if any) variable to whatever you want (say, to `-std=gnu++1z`).

For *clang* the path became `/usr/local/Qt-5.4.1/mkspecs/common/clang.conf` in my case.

For some other targets/compilers you may should to follow `Tools -> Options -> Build & Run -> Kits -> (select Kit you use) -> (look at 'Qt mkspec:' line at bottom)` then find in `/usr/local/Qt-5.4.1/mkspecs/*/qmake.conf` (where `*` is `Qt mkspec:` line contents) and in all included `*.conf` files a string `QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_CXX11` or `QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_CXX14`, that you need. Then change its value appropriately.

Then of course you need to use `CONFIG += c++11` or `CONFIG += c++14`, as [Jon Harper](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4732082/jon-harper) mentioned in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38293989/1430927).