# How to set qmake to C++14 with recent MinGW?

Tags: c++, qt, qmake

[I](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11066068/how-to-program-c11-using-qt5) [know](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2987062/configuring-the-gcc-compiler-switches-in-qt-qtcreator-and-qmake) [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38293708/compilation-of-c14-in-qtcreator) [are](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26127217/how-can-i-use-c14-features-when-building-qmake-projects) [many](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16948382/how-to-enable-c11-in-qt-creator) [duplicates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19398438/c-qt-how-to-add-std-c11-to-the-makefile-which-is-generated-by-qmake).

This is my Test.pro:

```
CONFIG += c++14
SOURCES += main.cpp
```

and my main.cpp:

```
int main(){}
```

According to the many duplicates this should give me C++14. However, when I build the project with **Qt Creator 4.2.0** with **Qt 5.8.0-1** and **MinGW gcc 5.3.0-1** installed via the maintenance tool I get

> g++ -c -pipe -fno-keep-inline-dllexport -g **-std=gnu++1y** -frtti -Wall -Wextra -fexceptions -mthreads -DUNICODE -DQT_QML_DEBUG -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_NEEDS_QMAIN -I..\Test -I. -IC:\Qt\5.8\mingw53_32\include -IC:\Qt\5.8\mingw53_32\include\QtGui -IC:\Qt\5.8\mingw53_32\include\QtANGLE -IC:\Qt\5.8\mingw53_32\include\QtCore -Idebug -IC:\Qt\5.8\mingw53_32\mkspecs\win32-g++  -o debug\main.o ..\Test\main.cpp

which is not the `-std=c++14` I expect.

I tried all kinds of tricks from other questions such as

```
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_CXX14 = -std=c++14
CONFIG += c++14
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -std=c++14

SOURCES += main.cpp
```

which results in

> g++ -c -pipe -fno-keep-inline-dllexport **-std=c++14** -g **-std=gnu++1y** -frtti -Wall -Wextra -fexceptions -mthreads -DUNICODE -DQT_QML_DEBUG -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_NEEDS_QMAIN -I..\Test -I. -IC:\Qt\5.8\mingw53_32\include -IC:\Qt\5.8\mingw53_32\include\QtGui -IC:\Qt\5.8\mingw53_32\include\QtANGLE -IC:\Qt\5.8\mingw53_32\include\QtCore -Idebug -IC:\Qt\5.8\mingw53_32\mkspecs\win32-g++  -o debug\main.o ..\Test\main.cpp

where the second option overwrites the first, meaning it is still in `gnu++1y`-mode or just

```
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -std=c++14
SOURCES += main.cpp
```

which also results in

> g++ -c -pipe -fno-keep-inline-dllexport **-std=c++14** -g **-std=gnu++11** -frtti -Wall -Wextra -fexceptions -mthreads -DUNICODE -DQT_QML_DEBUG -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_NEEDS_QMAIN -I..\Test -I. -IC:\Qt\5.8\mingw53_32\include -IC:\Qt\5.8\mingw53_32\include\QtGui -IC:\Qt\5.8\mingw53_32\include\QtANGLE -IC:\Qt\5.8\mingw53_32\include\QtCore -Idebug -IC:\Qt\5.8\mingw53_32\mkspecs\win32-g++  -o debug\main.o ..\Test\main.cpp

I deleted the build directory and the Test.pro.user file to force a build from scratch, nothing gave me C++14.

How do I tell qmake to use C++14?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The version of Qt that you're using doesn't explicitly support the compiler you're using. You can do **either one** of the following:

1. Set *both* `QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_CXX14` and `QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_GNUCXX14` in your project:

   ```
   win32-g++ {
      QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_CXX14 = -std=c++14
      QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_GNUCXX14 = -std=c++14
   }
   ```
2. Edit the default values of those two variables as above, in `mkspecs/win32-g++/qmake.conf` within your Qt installation folder.
3. Add a new `mkspec` copied from `win32-g++`, targeting your compiler, and build your Qt using it. All the project that use that Qt will then behave correctly w.r.t. C++14 support.

Comment: 2. Alone makes qmake pass the desired flag. There may be issues with the application not fitting to the Qt library due to different standards being used, but I could not produce such an error.

Comment: @nwp Of course 2. alone will do it. I listed these options as mutually exclusive: "You can do one of the following". I edited it to emphasize that. "There may be issues with the application not fitting to the Qt library due to different standards being used" Qt is meant to be valid C++11, and that means it's also valid C++14 (with very few odd corner cases that don't apply to Qt). If you worry about binary compatibility - that's unnecessary, those switches don't produce binary-incompatible output.